# Ionic Tutorial Fails When Installing node-sass Directory

Tags: ionic-framework, sass

I'm trying to run the Ionic tutorial on my system by running the following command (as detailed [at their Tutorial page in their docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/tutorial/) :

```
sudo ionic start MyIonicProject tutorial
```

However, the tutorial always fails when it tries to build the node-sass directory within MyIonicProject:

```
gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /Users/macdad/MyIonicProject/node_modules/node-sass/build
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/macdad/MyIonicProject/node_modules/node-sass/build'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/macdad/MyIonicProject/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/macdad/MyIonicProject/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.7.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.9.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.9.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/macdad/.npm/_logs/2018-08-02T01_58_32_378Z-debug.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess npm.

        npm i exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more 
        information.
```

Permission is denied when it attempts to build within the `node-sass/build` directory -- but how can I set permissions on a directory that doesn't yet exist?  An earlier error outputs the following when invoking mkdir:

`Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/imacuser/MyIonicProject/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'`

Parent directory does have read/write privileges. I see this question asked in different variations online but I can't find any definitive answer. Hard to learn a framework when you can't get the main tutorial running. Appreciate any help you can give the newb here.

EDIT: Adding the full result of the two commands suggested by @ZearaeZ after applying the read/write privileges to all enclosed items. The build still fails:

```
MacBook-Pro-6:~ macdad$ sudo npm rebuild node-sass --force
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
MacBook-Pro-6:~ macdad$ sudo ionic start MyIonicProject
? ./MyIonicProject exists. Overwrite? Yes

Let's pick the perfect starter template! 

Starter templates are ready-to-go Ionic apps that come packed with everything 
you need to build your app. To bypass this prompt next time, supply template, 
the second argument to ionic start.

? Starter template: tabs
✔ Preparing directory ./MyIonicProject - done!
✔ Downloading and extracting tabs starter - done!
? Integrate your new app with Cordova to target native iOS and Android? Yes
> ionic integrations enable cordova --quiet
✔ Downloading integration cordova - done!
✔ Copying integrations files to project - done!
[OK] Integration cordova added!

Installing dependencies may take several minutes.

     ✨   IONIC  DEVAPP   ✨

 Speed up development with the Ionic DevApp, our fast, on-device testing mobile app

  -     Test on iOS and Android without Native SDKs
  -     LiveReload for instant style and JS updates

 -->    Install DevApp: https://bitly/ionic-dev-app    <--

────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

> npm i
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@2.11.3: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.

> fsevents@1.2.4 install /Users/macdad/MyIonicProject/node_modules/fsevents
> node install

[fsevents] Success: "/Users/macdad/MyIonicProject/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v57-darwin-x64/fse.node" already installed
Pass --update-binary to reinstall or --build-from-source to recompile

> node-sass@4.9.0 install /Users/macdad/MyIonicProject/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Unable to save binary /Users/macdad/MyIonicProject/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-57 : { Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/macdad/MyIonicProject/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'
    at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:885:18)
    at sync (/Users/macdad/MyIonicProject/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:71:13)
    at Function.sync (/Users/macdad/MyIonicProject/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:77:24)
    at checkAndDownloadBinary (/Users/macdad/MyIonicProject/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:114:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/macdad/MyIonicProject/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:157:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  path: '/Users/macdad/MyIonicProject/node_modules/node-sass/vendor' }

> uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall /Users/macdad/MyIonicProject/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
> node lib/post_install.js


> node-sass@4.9.0 postinstall /Users/macdad/MyIonicProject/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: /usr/local/bin/node /Users/macdad/MyIonicProject/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
gyp verb cli   '/Users/macdad/MyIonicProject/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@8.11.3 | darwin | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/Users/macdad/MyIonicProject/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/Users/macdad/MyIonicProject/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/Users/macdad/MyIonicProject/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/macdad/MyIonicProject/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/macdad/MyIonicProject/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/macdad/MyIonicProject/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 { Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/Users/macdad/MyIonicProject/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/Users/macdad/MyIonicProject/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/Users/macdad/MyIonicProject/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/macdad/MyIonicProject/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/macdad/MyIonicProject/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/macdad/MyIonicProject/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python2\n    at getNotFoundError (/Users/macdad/MyIonicProject/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)\n    at F (/Users/macdad/MyIonicProject/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)\n    at E (/Users/macdad/MyIonicProject/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)\n    at /Users/macdad/MyIonicProject/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16\n    at /Users/macdad/MyIonicProject/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5\n    at /Users/macdad/MyIonicProject/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5\n    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python /usr/bin/python
gyp verb check python version `/usr/bin/python -c "import sys; print "2.7.10
gyp verb check python version .%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];"` returned: %j
gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 8.11.3
gyp verb command install [ '8.11.3' ]
gyp verb install input version string "8.11.3"
gyp verb install installing version: 8.11.3
gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
gyp verb install version is good
gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 8.11.3
gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /Users/macdad/MyIonicProject/node_modules/node-sass/build
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/macdad/MyIonicProject/node_modules/node-sass/build'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/macdad/MyIonicProject/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/macdad/MyIonicProject/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.9.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.9.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/macdad/.npm/_logs/2018-08-09T13_25_52_106Z-debug.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess npm.

        npm i exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more 
        information.
```

As suggested by me, it makes sense that I can't have permissions on that directory, since the `node-sass` directory is created at runtime and, if that does not have read/write privileges automatically, it's hard to add them if they don't exist.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to assign permissions to users and groups.

1. Select a disk, folder, or file, then choose File > Get Info.
2. click the lock icon to unlock it, then enter an administrator name
       and password.
3. Click a user or group in the Name column, then choose a privilege
           setting from the pop-up menu and give Read & Write access.
4. Click the Action pop-up menu (Crog Icon), then choose “Apply to
       enclosed items.”

After applying permission to your directory Run this command in your project directory.

```
sudo npm rebuild node-sass --force
```

It will forcefully rebuild node-sass in your project directory.

Comment: Sorry to say, it fails at the very beginning: `Unable to save binary /Users/imacuser/MyIonicProject/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-57 : { Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/imacuser/MyIonicProject/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'`

Comment: It is because Your user doesnot have any access to create folder. To solve this issue RightClick on your project folder >> Click on Get Info >> There might be a lock sign click on this lock sign >> Rnter an administrator name and password and click OK >> in the bottom of the dialog there assign Read and Write access to your user >> click on setting (crog icon) >> Apply to enclosed items >> Click on OK. After that sun same command "sudo npm rebuild node-sass --force".

Comment: Didn't work, unfortunately. I'm going to re-edit my original question to add the full result of both commands after applying all to enclosed items (which I thought I had done, but that was another computer).

Comment: Can you please try this once: sudo npm install --unsafe-perm node-sass

Comment: That certainly installs it -- but in order to run the tutorial, it needs to overwrite the current project files in `MyIonicProject`, meaning it needs to reinstall the `node-sass` directory. Otherwise, the result is: `Not erasing existing project in ./MyIonicProject.` and returning to the prompt. See the third and fourth lines in the code same after EDIT above: `MacBook-Pro-6:~ macdad$ sudo ionic start MyIonicProject

? ./MyIonicProject exists. Overwrite? Yes`

Comment: Your error says `EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/macdad/MyIonicProject/node_modules/node-sass/build'` that mean you dont have permission to create folder in this location. Right click your project and there you will find a lock icon click there. Enter your Computer username and password to unlock it. there you will find Permission section over there to give full permission to your user. Give permission and lock that icon again. Try running npm rebuild node-sass --force again to install node-sass to your project directory

Comment: Correct -- as noted above, the `build` directory is being created within a `node-sass` directory which does not exist unless I run `sudo ionic start MyIonicProject tutorial`. Again, adding permissions for the project folder has no impact on subsequent folders that are created at runtime with their own permissions issues. I'll post this question to the Ionic board and will report back if I receive any solutions. Thanks for your help.